# Unable to read Supression file

Tags: java, maven

ERROR Unable to read Suppression file

[image: 1]

I'm running a build after adding a CVE to suppress with an XML suppression file. I've linked the suppression file within the POM file under the dependency-check-maven configuration. The POM and suppression are located within the same folder in my project structure.

Tried:

- adding a path using ${basedir}/ before the suppression file name.

POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.snhu</groupId>
<artifactId>rest-service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>rest-service</name>
<description>Project for CS-305 Module 6</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.46</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    <plugin>
          <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
          <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
          <version>7.1.1</version>
          <configuration>
               <suppressionFiles>
                    <suppressionFile>suppression-new.xml</suppressionFile>
            </suppressionFiles>   
            </configuration>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>check</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
         
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and post the error details as text and not as an image. Refer to [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Issue has been resolved.

Comment: @TracyMarston how did you resolve the issue?